# Elsa 2 Workflow ForEach Iterator variable

Tags: c#, elsa-workflows

I need to create a workflow inside my project. So I added Elsa (2.5) Workflow Engine and started with the workflow designer. Now I need to add a for each loop and **access the iterator variable**.

**Question: How do I access the current iterating object?**

My sample workflow:

[image]

How I set the collection (every thing works fine here, send mail will be executed for example three times):

[image]

And now I need to access values from my current collection entry:

[image]

Can anyone assist on how I can access this value? I can't find any documention of the current version..

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found the answer by myself:

[image]